# Redux RTK Query - useGet..Query does not update cache or does not request data from server

Tags: redux, rtk-query

[image]

[image]

Here's the definition for the query, when I navigate to a page or the app restarts, all useGet...Query just returns the cache data (the data with the specific parameter indicated in the red box). Why does it not update when the page rerenders and only returns cache data? I will set many invalidate tags to ensure it can be forced to refetch but it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

As I'm working with the expo, I don't know why but after I uninstalled the expo and re-install it then it works fine.